# TSQL - How to compare volume count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a report that has a date range of total volume count each day.  I'm not sure how to write the TSQL on how to compare a low volume count at a given date range. For example, How can I determine that the low volume count is 581 on the given dates?

[image]

Comment: Judging by the diversity of answers (all correct) perhaps it would help if you supplied the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(volume_count) as Min_volume_count FROM tableName WHERE date= 'yourdate'
```

example

```
SELECT MIN(volume_count) as Min_volume_count FROM tableName WHERE date= '2018-03-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the window function **min() over**

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,MinVol    = min(Volume) over () 
      ,Change    = Volume - min(Volume) over () 
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Volume  MinVol  Change
2018-03-01  581     581     0
2018-02-22  9480    581     8899
2018-02-15  10082   581     9501
2018-02-08  10082   581     9501
2018-02-01  10504   581     9923
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ddate, min(volume) as mmin 
from table 
group by ddate 
order by ddate
```